# Microsoft HoloLens image capture not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, hololens, image-capture

I am trying to capture an image using HoloLens. I accept the permission to use the HoloLens camera.

I am using this code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WebCam;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WebCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    PhotoCapture photoCaptureObject = null;
    Texture2D targetTexture = null;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Resolution cameraResolution = PhotoCapture.SupportedResolutions.OrderByDescending((res) => res.width * res.height).First();
        targetTexture = new Texture2D(cameraResolution.width, cameraResolution.height);

        // Create a PhotoCapture object
        PhotoCapture.CreateAsync(false, delegate (PhotoCapture captureObject) {
            photoCaptureObject = captureObject;
            CameraParameters cameraParameters = new CameraParameters();
            cameraParameters.hologramOpacity = 0.0f;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionWidth = cameraResolution.width;
            cameraParameters.cameraResolutionHeight = cameraResolution.height;
            cameraParameters.pixelFormat = CapturePixelFormat.BGRA32;

            // Activate the camera
            photoCaptureObject.StartPhotoModeAsync(cameraParameters, delegate (PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result) {
                // Take a picture
                photoCaptureObject.TakePhotoAsync(OnCapturedPhotoToMemory);
            });
        });
    }

    void OnCapturedPhotoToMemory(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result, PhotoCaptureFrame photoCaptureFrame)
    {
        // Copy the raw image data into the target texture

        photoCaptureFrame.UploadImageDataToTexture(targetTexture);

        // Create a GameObject to which the texture can be applied
        GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
        Renderer quadRenderer = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>() as Renderer;
        quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture"));

        quad.transform.parent = this.transform;
        quad.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);

        quadRenderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", targetTexture);

        // Deactivate the camera
        photoCaptureObject.StopPhotoModeAsync(OnStoppedPhotoMode);
    }

    void OnStoppedPhotoMode(PhotoCapture.PhotoCaptureResult result)
    {
        // Shutdown the photo capture resource
        photoCaptureObject.Dispose();
        photoCaptureObject = null;
    }
}
```

This script was attached to an empty game object.

I am getting the following error

```
ArgumentNullException:  Value cannot be null
Parameter name: shader.UnityEngine.Material..ctor(UnityEngine.Shader shader) (at <00000000000000000000>:0)
```

Please can anyone help to capture an image. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Is this line of code that throws this error: `quadRenderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture"));` If you have commented this code line, it's not possible to throw the exception with the same messages. Could you please confirm the latest exception and error message? As a test, please create a test shader and call Shader.Find() to obatin it.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a shader located here, "Custom/Unlit/UnlitTexture". Which may be unavailable. 
I'd suggest commenting out that line to determine if the other code around it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 changes:

1. in Unity Editor, Edit > Project Settings > Graphics > to the list "Always included shaders", Add "Unlit/Texture"
2. Update the line in the code to Shader.Find("Unlit/Texture");